# Front page makes it look like my old activity was recent on a re-opened question

Tags: bug, editing, closed-questions, re-open

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6447/eating-before-leaning-on-esther) was [re-opened](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/6447/revisions) today by msh210. When he re-opened it, the last content activity on the post had been an [edit by me](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/6447/4), a year ago. I noticed a few minutes later that it was listed on the front page as "23m ago Isaac Moses,"<sup>1</sup> which seems to imply that I'd done something to it 23 minutes ago, which I hadn't.

I suggest that in this situation, one of the following should be displayed:

- *1 yr ago Isaac Moses* - reflecting the time and author of the last content change.
- *23m ago msh210* - reflecting the time and author of the most recent activity that put it on the front page
- *23m ago* - reflecting the time it got onto the front page and concealing who re-opened it

---

<sup>1. I'm sorry that I don't have a screenshot, and I can't show this state now because the question has since been edited.</sup>

Comment: I've noticed this before on reopenings. We can open another PT question if you want and get a screenshot.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks, but I'm not sure that's necessary unless someone disputes the veracity of my report. If the devs are going to address this, they can do testing on their sandbox system.

Comment: I have also noticed this (and saw this specific case when it happened, though I didn't think to snap a screen shot either).

Comment: [Same question at MSO.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132158) (A tip of my hat to [animuson](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/29942/animuson) for pointing me to it.)